# We invade at midnight

Tags: grammar

Why do they use the simple present tense for a future action? It starts at 4:10

"We invade at midnight.

https://youtu.be/NvKzPZl3Bds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present simple is used to **state facts**.

It similar to: The train leaves at ten. The class gets out at five.

I found a great site for English:

1. Use the simple present to talk about
   habits or routines, schedules, and facts.
   [Simple Present](https://ngl.cengage.com/assets/downloads/grex_pro0000000538/grex1_su3.pdf)

More here: [**National Geographic English Learning**](https://eltngl.com/)

Comment: thanks a lot. Isn't present progressive also used to talk about timetables and schedules? I can't find the discussion but if I am not mistaken it was mentioned in that discussion that present continuous can also be used in such examples as "The lesson starts at 5" and "The  train leaves at 5."

Comment: @AntoniaA The present continuous is not used **if you are specifically referring to a thing listed a schedule or timetable**. So, the invasion is scheduled for a particular time. That's the idea.

Comment: if I use "we are invading" it would refer to an arrangement. Right? But it's also correct.

Comment: @AntoniaA I cannot keep explaining the thing over and over. It can refer to a military **plan**. Just because of this one use does not mean the continuous can't be used. It's like any other simple versus continuous verb use.